# Where did Kant's headstone go?

Tags: kant, history

I recently attended a lecture on Kant where the lecturer told us he visited Kant's grave a few years back. Apparently the grave is still there in Königsberg, but the headstone was nowhere to be found. This is the one: https://www.college.columbia.edu/core/sites/core/files/styles/large/public/images/Kant%27s_tombstone_Kaliningrad.jpeg?itok=PuAfoQKy

Is it known where the headstone is now? Apparently the guides at the gravesite didn't know where it was.

Answer (score 2):

The poin (1) on the screenhot is the Kant's tomb, which is located at the back of the Cathedral near the place where The University of Königsberg used to be.

The point (2) is approximately 400 meters from the tomb at the beginning of the bridge across Kneiphof iseland. This is the place where the headstone is located at the moment.

P.S. To my knowledge, this is not a headstone of the tomb. It is a memorial tablet, which was placed on a wall of the Königsberg Castle (in 1904), which was damaged during the WWII and demolished in 1967. The tablet was lost during the war. In 1993 the tablet was recreated and placed where the castle used to be.

[image]

Comment: Point (1) is where the tomb is right? What is point (2)?

Comment: @Yorick Sorry, the answer was incomplete, I've just edited